# i have an error at nodejs with 'oracledb'

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-oracledb

I have an error with oracledb modules.

I have successed to install oracledb.

when i typed like this,

> **-> npm install oracledb**
>
>     njsOracle.cpp
>     njsPool.cpp
>     njsConnection.cpp
>     njsResultSet.cpp
>     njsMessages.cpp
>     njsIntLob.cpp
>     dpiEnv.cpp
>     dpiEnvImpl.cpp
>     dpiException.cpp
>     dpiExceptionImpl.cpp
>     dpiConnImpl.cpp
>     dpiDateTimeArrayImpl.cpp
>     dpiPoolImpl.cpp
>     dpiStmtImpl.cpp
>     dpiUtils.cpp
>     dpiLob.cpp
>     dpiCommon.cpp
>     win_delay_load_hook.cc
>     
>   C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.lib 라이브러리 및 C:\Users\aaa
>     \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.exp 개체를 생성하고 있습니다.
>     코드를 생성하고 있습니다.
>     코드를 생성했습니다.
>     oracledb.vcxproj -> C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node
>     oracledb.vcxproj -> C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.pdb (Full PDB)
>   C:\Users\GwiTtaeGi\AppData\Roaming\npm
>   `-- oracledb@1.13.1

but when i execute **require('oracledb')**, there's an error like this.

> Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
>   \?\c:\testnode\test\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. 
> (c:\testnode\test\node_modules\oracledb\lib\oracledb.js:35:19)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)

I can't fix this error..

version is..
node -v : v6.10.3
npm -v : 4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, try to clean NPM cache

`rm -rf ~/.node-gyp ~/.npm; npm cache clean`

- If error still occurs, try set NODE_PATH environment variable